# how to show and play binary data that changes every second

Tags: javascript, python, html, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

i am **scraping** live stream from one website.in **scraping** live stream i am using websocket connection to server and server give me binary data of live stream every second.
my python code looks like following:-

```
    import websocket
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time
from base64 import b64encode
import requests
import base64 
import json

def on_message(ws, message):
    try:
        json.loads(message)
        print(message)
        print("json found")
    except ValueError:
        test={}    
        f = open("data.mp4","ab") # write or append we can do anything
        f.write(message)
    
    # f = open("data.mp4","ab")
    # f.write(message)
# 
def on_error(ws, error):
    print("on error")
    print(error)

def on_close(ws,d,c):
    print(d)
    print(c)
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("open")
    def run(*args):    
        while True:
            ws.send("Hello")
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

def connect():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://bintu-h5live-secure.nanocosmos.de/h5live/authstream/stream.mp4/?url=rtmp%3A%2F%2Fbintu-splay.nanocosmos.de%3A1935%2Fsplay&stream=Av7gf-8VFKd&cid=788213&pid=15225378643&token=498926e198c330ffcb8e25e7470fe1a6%2Beea9c39334dca9b5aa2d7d31ed28abf2&expires=1622528020&options=13&tag=teen20",
                              on_open = on_open,on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error,on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever(origin="https://beeta777.com")
```

here problem is i want to show live stream to my website. how can i show it to my website ?

Comment: I think for this you would have to do a lot of work something we could not guide you though on stack overflow or use FFMPEG and a Python wrapper around it, something that might help https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/6926ty/how_do_i_capture_a_live_stream/

Comment: probably if you would send it in normal way then you would need only tag `<video>` and browser would do the rest. If you send it in websocket then you will have to write code in JavaScript which get data from socket and update image on `Canvas` or replace image as base64 in `<img src="data: base64 ... ">`

Comment: Can you please sent js code for it ? Fetch data from my python websocket server and serve and put it on html page . I tried before but not working

Comment: What did you try? In what way is it not working?

Comment: I simply add video tag . Src as my video mp4 fiel that continuously appended but html page does not load new data so when we refresh for new data it stats from first second instead of last second when video is paused.